# asp.net core web api on Azure always is production?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I am trying to publish my asp.net core web API on the azure web app. even though i choose debug mode, the app on azure always is in production.

does anyone know the reason?

And the appsetting.Development.json seem no working!

Can you help me?

Comment: You can configure on `azure portal` and can select `debug mode` there. Why do you want to publish on debug mode? To do remote debugging?

Comment: you can set "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development", then it should work

Comment: we have 3 web apps.   one for dev, one for qa. and  uat.

Comment: you mean you have three deployment environment ? or three separate instance of application ?

Comment: in fact we have 3 Azure subscriptions.  so i must config one for dev